# Recieving the error: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'

Tags: c#, mysql

I am working on importing an excel spreadsheet into a form using c#.
When I run my code and try to upload an excel spreadsheet, I keep getting the following error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'

on the line:

```
myDa.Fill(myDS, myTable);
```

this is my code:

```
private void ReadMySqlData(string myTable)
{
    UpdateStatus("Reading Database Table");
    Database DB = new Database();
    DB.DBConnection();
    var myCmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM "+myTable+";", DB.myCon);
    myCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@table", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = myTable;
    MySqlDataAdapter myDa = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    myDa.SelectCommand = myCmd;
    UpdateStatus("Copying Remote Table to local!");
    myDa.Fill(myDS, myTable);
    UpdateStatus("");
}
```

Comment: apparently database connection is failing

Comment: Reading your error message, seems like your problem is not related to excel but database related (I have edited your question). Looking at your code, looks like mySQL. Check your database connection string and feel free to edit your question and add more relevant (database related) information

Comment: What does your connection string look like? This means that either the DB server you are trying to connect is not allowing the connection to be made or your have a typo in your connection `string`

Comment: private bool ReadExcelFile(string xlsFileLocation, string xlsTable, string xlsSheet)
        {
            try
            {
                UpdateStatus("Reading Excel File");
                string conString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + xlsFileLocation + "';Extended Properties = 'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Imex=1';";
                var xlsCon = new OleDbConnection();
                xlsCon.ConnectionString = conString;

Comment: Side points: Unless you have a way of verifying the input of `myTable`, you have dangerous SQL injection here. Also you are missing `using` on your connection, command and adapter. You should *not* cache the connection object, create it when you need it and dispose as soon as you are done.